# generate random number from normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

Can any one explain in which range I am going to get random numbers, if I was said generate random number from normal distribution with mean=50 and std_dev=25,

what does it exactly means..I tried to find the ans but have some doubts.

Comment: A normal random variable can take on *any* real number.

Comment: ok...so what does mean and std_dev signifies?

Comment: It tells you how likely to get a number close to the mean. The higher the standard deviation, the higher chance to get a number far away from the mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are N randomly generated numbers from normal distribution, and the mean, $\mu$, standard deviation, $\sigma$, the 68–95–99.7 rule, also known as the three-sigma rule or empirical rule, states that nearly all values lie within three standard deviations of the mean in a normal distribution.

68.27% of the values lie within one standard deviation of the mean. Similarly, 95.45% of the values lie within two standard deviations of the mean. Nearly all (99.73%) of the values lie within three standard deviations of the mean.

$ 
\begin{align}
  \Pr(\mu-\;\,\sigma \le x \le \mu+\;\,\sigma) &\approx 0.6827 \\
  \Pr(\mu-2\sigma \le x \le \mu+2\sigma)       &\approx 0.9545 \\
  \Pr(\mu-3\sigma \le x \le \mu+3\sigma)       &\approx 0.9973
\end{align}
$

Answer (score 0):

To solve this use Inverse Cumulative Distribution function. You need a uniform [0,1) random source (any would do), and you just sample InvCDF with those random numbers and it will produce the required result.

Comment: This procedure is essentially never used for the normal distribution, because computing the inverse of the CDF is relatively expensive. A specialized algorithm for the normal distribution is the Box-Muller algorithm. This exploits the fact that the Euclidean norm of a pair of independent standard normal random variables has an elementary CDF, and the fact that the distribution of such a pair of variables is uniform on each circle.

Comment: Another alternative is the more general ziggurat algorithm, which is harder to implement but generally faster.

Comment: Cool, didn't know about that, I always kind of relied on InvCDF. Then again, I never had any need for a huge set of randoms, so it was never an issue.

Comment: Oh, since it is new to you, let me spell out the Box-Muller algorithm, since it is so simple. Notice that the CDF of the Euclidean norm of two independent standard normals is $0$ for $x \leq 0$ and $\int_0^x y e^{-y^2/2} dy = \int_0^{x^2/2} e^{-u} du = 1-e^{-x^2/2}$ for $x>0$. So you can sample the norm as $\sqrt{-2 \ln(U_1)}$, where $U_1$ is uniform on $(0,1)$. Then you can sample the angle uniformly from the unit circle, i.e. take $U_2$ uniform on $(0,2 \pi)$, then the point on the unit circle you want is $(\cos(U_2),\sin(U_2))$.

Comment: Now the result is $(\sqrt{-2 \ln(U_1)} \cos(U_2),\sqrt{-2 \ln(U_1)}\sin(U_2))$.